# Can zsh do smartcase completion like vim's search?

Tags: zsh, zsh-completion

Vim has a "smartcase" feature, which makes searching case insensitive, but only if the search contains all lowercase letters. When you search on any uppercase letters, smartcase assumes you want a case sensitive search. Is there a way to get the same behavior in zsh's tab completion?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Take a look at my zshrc file.

https://github.com/martincanaval/arch-conf/tree/master/etc/zsh

I have that functionality you are asking for and I believe this line made it.

```
zstyle ':completion:*'  matcher-list 'm:{a-z}={A-Z}'
```

Comment: Brilliant. I had `m:{a-zA-Z}={A-Za-z}` that I'd copied from somewhere, and I just replaced it with that.

Interesting note, the exact meaning smartcase in Vim is that the entire string is case-sensitive if it contains any uppercase letters. In this zsh variant, only the uppercase letters within the string are case-sensitive. I think I actually like this way better.

Comment: Oh, the credit isn't mine, I took that (and most of my .zshrc) from the [grml zsh site](http://grml.org/zsh/). Glad it helped.

Comment: I find that only adding this command does not work. After that, we have to use `autoload -U compinit  && compinit` to make case-insensitive completion work.

Comment: Did your github repository go somewhere else, the link is dead?

Comment: `zstyle ':completion:*' matcher-list '' '+m:{a-zA-Z}={A-Za-z}' '+r:|[._-]=* r:|=*' '+l:|=* r:|=*'` is more allowing.

Comment: @HappyFace `zstyle ':completion:*' matcher-list '' '+m:{a-zA-Z}={A-Za-z}' '+r:|[._-]=* r:|=*' '+l:|=* r:|=*'` is incorrect: depending on what one has in the directory, the case of characters already typed is not always corrected to the right ones, giving a nonexistent file name.